# Looking for Liptchitz and $C^1$ operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am  looking for operators that meet the following criteria: $m: L^2(0,1) \rightarrow L^{\infty}(0,1)$ and possess both Lipschitz and $C^1$ class properties.

One idea I have in mind is to use the expression $m(y) = \|f(y)\|_{L^p(0,1)}$, where $p=1,2$, and  $f:L^2(0,1) \to L^2(0,1)$ is a Nemytskii operator  non-null and satisfies the properties of being Lipschitz and of class $C^1$. Is it a correct example?

Any other suggestions or insights on this topic would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance for your help.